# What do I need to do to get these both to run in different threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

I've got two functions `main` and `detection`. I need them to run at the same time, I'm trying to do this via two different threads.

`main` is made up of multiple small functions and is responsible for GUI interactions on an application window. This runs in an loop, it constantly checks to see if it wants to perform GUI interactions. Almost all of them are simply clicking to close notifications within the application window.

```
def main():
    while True:
        if check():
            doSomething1()
            doSomething2()
            doSomething3()
```

`detection` loads a few thousand images and then checks to see if it's ready to run image detection via a pixel colour match. I realise it's loading the images on every iteration of it's `while` loop. That's important as `doSomething4` appends and sorts images for it to load and try to detect. The performance is fine, they're very simple images.

```
class VideoCaptureThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, result_queue: queue.Queue) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.exit_signal = threading.Event()
        self.result_queue = result_queue

def run(self) -> None:
    while not self.exit_signal.wait(0.05):
        try:
            result = videoLoop()
            self.result_queue.put(result)
        except Exception as exc:
            print(f"Failed capture: {exc}")

def detection():
    result_queue = queue.Queue()
    thread = VideoCaptureThread(result_queue=result_queue)
    thread.start()
    while True:
        window = result_queue.get()
        # load images to detect 
        images = loadImages(avoid)
        # check if ready to run detection
        x, y = 1742, 979
        r,g,b = py.pixel(x, y)
        if b == 106:
            if shipDetection(images , 0.98, window, 50):
                continue
            else:
                doSomething4()
```

Someone on here helped get the detection thread running correctly but I can't seem to get `main` to start. I was told I need to initiate `main` before `detection` as it's loop will block/lock my code.

```
t = Thread(name='bot', target=main)
t.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    detection()
```

If I run `t.start` in a separate script I can get a thread to start without issue, but here `detection` runs correctly while `main` appears to start running (a window appears when it starts) but nothing updates from there.

`doSomething1` should return 11 frames of a specific section of the application window and display it (`find` is a separate function loaded from another script that displays things).

Instead, I'm only getting 1 frame from `doSomething1`.

```
def doSomething1(object, y_0, y_1, x_0, x_1, x_adjustment, y_adjustment):
    for z in range (0, 10):
        haystack = app_window.get_haystack()
        location = haystack[y_0:y_1, x_0:x_1]
        img = object.find(location, 0.92, 'points1','Refit')
        if img:
            return True
```

**What do I need to do to get these both to run in different threads?**

Comment: What does `videoLoop` do?  You said "a window comes up".  What GUI are you running?  Typically, GUI frameworks must run in the main thread, and do not return from their main loop until the window is closed.

Comment: Hi Tim, both functions are responsible for different GUI interactions on the same application. It's essentially a fairly simply set for `main` and a fairly complicated set for `detection` but both are checking for images on a screen and then interacting with the screen. I've been trying to run these both at the same time. One thread for each set of interactions. This is because the interactions from `main` address fairly random events, while the interactions for `detection` are very predictable. So I'm trying to run `detection` and catch the unpredictable events with `main`

Comment: Re, "...a window appears when it starts, but nothing updates..." You are asking for help to understand why your GUI window doesn't behave as you expected, but you have not shown even one line of code in your example that has anything to do with GUI windows.

Comment: Building on what @TimRoberts said, In most GUI frameworks, your code doesn't sit in the driver's seat. The framework provides a "main" function that loops forever, awaiting _events_ —key presses, mouse clicks, timers going off, etc. When an event happens, the GUI calls your _handler_ functions, which tell it how to respond. Depending on what GUI framework you are using, it might be possible for your program to create a window on-screen before your program enters the GUI's main loop, but if your program _never_ enters the main loop, then it would be no surprise if nothing appears in the window.

Comment: Sorry I think there is a misunderstanding. I am not generating a GUI interface. I am performing interactions using the windows inbuild GUI (I'm clicking on things). That's what I mean by GUI interactions.

Comment: What I meant by window is OpenCVs `im.show` function. It displays a small section of the screen for troubleshooting proposes. I didn't think it relevant because I know it's working independently of this attempt to get two threads working. That's handled (and the OP mentions it) by the `find` function. Both functions work correctly if I run them by themselves. I can't figure out how to have two sets of `while` loops running at once.